# delete a child object from an array collection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I assigned a data that is returned from an API to a variable named `today` and I'm trying to perform a delete function on it but I'm always getting this error `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

**DATA**

```
[
    {
        "id":324,
        "firstName":"Chris",
        "lastName":"Jake",
        "orders":[
            {
                "id":162,
                "meals":[
                    {
                        "id":27,
                        "name":"French Fries",
                        "description":"test",
                    },
                    {
                        "id":28,
                        "name":"Plain Rice, Beans and Fish",
                        "description":"test",
                    }
                ],
                "serveDate":"2019-07-16 00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

FUNCTION

```
delete() {
    for (let r = 0; r < this.today.length; r++) {
        if (this.today[r].orders[r].id === this.orderId) {
            this.today.splice(r, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's best practice to parse JSON result first. Then proceed to do your operation. Typescript is strongly typed and you have to be careful with js style manipulating data.

Answer (score 0):

Your "serverDate" is an element of the array as well and it doesn't have the id, therefore you get this error. order[r].id will return false if undefined.

```
  delete() {
      for (let r = 0; r < this.today.length; r++) {
            if (this.today[r].orders[r].id && 
                this.today[r].orders[r].id ===   this.orderId) {
                this.today.splice(r, 1);
            }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 delete() {
    this.today.forEach((el, i) => {
      el.orders.forEach((order, j) => {
        if (order.id == this.orderId) {
          this.today[i].orders.splice(j,1);
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you receive JSON object in angular service and can remove the data like this.

```
const data =  `[{
    "id":324,
    "firstName":"Chris",
    "lastName":"Jake",
    "orders":[
        {
            "id":162,
            "meals":[
                {
                    "id":27,
                    "name":"French Fries",
                    "description":"test"
                },
                {
                    "id":28,
                    "name":"Plain Rice, Beans and Fish",
                    "description":"test"
                }
            ],
            "serveDate":"2019-07-16 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}]`;

let parse = JSON.parse(data); console.log(parse);

const orderid = 27;
console.log(parse[0].orders[0].meals);
for(let i = 0; i < parse[0].orders[0].meals.length; i++ ) {
    if(parse[0].orders[0].meals[i].id == orderid) {
        parse[0].orders[0].meals.splice(i, 1)
    }
}
console.log(parse)
```

However there are easier way if you know your http endpoint.

Meal Interface

```
export interface meal{
    id: num | string;
    name: string;
    description: string
}
```

Order Interface

```
export interface order{
    id: num | string;
    meals: meal[];
    serveDate: string;
}
```

Data Interface

```
export interface data {
    id: num|string;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    orders: order[];
}
```

In your service
    this.http.get(this.dataurl)

so basically u can go through your json model with model after subscribe

```
this.http.get<data[]>(this.dataurl).subscribe(result => {
    if(result != null) {
        for(let u of result)
        {
            for(let o of u.orders)
            {
                for(let m of o.meals)
                {
                    if(orderid === m.id)
                    {
                     //remove your item from array
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other answer. "serverDate is not an element of the orders array. It's an element of the first object in the orders array. Where I think you're going wrong is with your for loop structure. To see this, let's break down what's happening on each loop:

```js
for (let r = 0; r < today.length; r++) {
    if (today[r].orders[r].id === this.orderId) {
        today.splice(r, 1);
    }
}

//r == 0
today[r].orders[r].id === this.orderId //grabs the 0th element of the today array and the 0th element of the orders array

//r == 1
today[r].orders[r].id === this.orderId //grabs the 1st element of the today array and the 1st element of the orders array

//!! the rest of the orders in today[0] and the order at location today[1].order[0] are skipped!!
```

In order to prevent this problem, you should use nested for loops.

```js
for (let r = 0; r < today.length; r++) { 
    for (let s=0 ; s < today[r].orders.length; s++) { 
        if (today[r].orders[s].id===t his.orderId) { 
            //splice whichever you want r for the day, s for the order 
        }
    }
}
```